# getting data from MYSQL database to a html tabel using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I design a table with html (bootstrap style) now i want to get data from my database table and fetch it in table using php, here is my html code:
Thanks for you help. :)

```
            <div class="ibox-content">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Register Date</th>
                <th>Occurrence Date</th>
                <th>Province</th>
                <th>User</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr class="gradeX">
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td class="center">test</td>
                <td class="center">test</td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

PHP code i tried but i didnt get any result it gives me errors:

```
<?php
      $username = "root";
      $password = "=";
      $host = "localhost";

      $connector = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)
          or die("Unable to connect");
        echo "Connections are made successfully::";
      $selected = mysql_select_db("user", $connector)
        or die("Unable to connect");

      //execute the SQL query and return records
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_one ");
      ?>
            <div class="ibox-content">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Register Date</th>
                <th>Occurrence Date</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr class="gradeX">
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td class="center">test</td>
                <td class="center">test</td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
          while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
            echo
            "<tr>
          echo "<td>" . $row['Category'] . "</td>";
              <td>{$row\['regdate'\]}</td>
              <td>{$row\['occdate'\]}</td>
            </tr>\n";
          }
        ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to connect to a database and run a query or literally asking us to do that for you? Attempt to do it based off tutorials then come back if it doesn't work. You'll learn more by doing it yourself than copying and pasting an answer.

Comment: Where is your php code, what does the data structure look like you are tryign to grab, do you know how to conenct to your database, etc.

Comment: @Matt i tried a php code but i didnt get any result : )

Comment: @Andrew yes i can connect to database

Comment: @saboorsaboor put in your php code then; we help fix errors not write code for you :)

Comment: @Matt I re-edit the post take a look Thanks: )

Answer (score 0):

Since `mysql_*` is depreciated I will answer this using `mysqli_*`.

You have already closed the table in your example before looping through the fetched data so I am unsure *where* you want these rows to populate however I made a guess.

Another error with your attempt is you have echo " ... echo "";

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table_one';
$data = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
?>

<div class="ibox-content">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables-example" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Register Date</th>
                <th>Occurrence Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) 
{
    echo "  <tr>
                <td>" . $row['Category'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['regdate'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['occdate'] . "</td>
            </tr>";
}
?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have indented the echo inside the while loop to keep it inline with the other html.

Comment: i get error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/..... on line 10 :(

Comment: @saboorsaboor can you let me know which line is line 10? Might be a simple missing ' or ) etc.

Comment: i get the data from database but with no text like (blank) it only gives me 7 blank rows, :)

Comment: Can you edit your post with your table structure, and add the newly edited code as well to double check nothing went wrong during copy/paste thanks

Comment: @saboorsaboor out of interest, what was the issue :)? Glad its working now.